xfce4-power-manager only runs when charging is plugged in (dietpi)
So I installed XFCE desktop on top of DietPi. So far it works for me, but the Power Manager is not functioning properly.
When I try to launch it, then it just doesn't launch. When I try to launch it from the terminal, I get these errors:
jerry@DietPi:~$ xfce4-power-manager
Xlib:  extension "DPMS" missing on display ":0.0".

(xfce4-power-manager:10572): xfce4-power-manager-WARNING **: 16:47:57.617: Monitor is not DPMS capable

(xfce4-power-manager:10572): xfce4-power-manager-WARNING **: 16:47:57.703: could not map keysym 1008ffa8 to keycode


(xfce4-power-manager:10572): GLib-GObject-CRITICAL **: 16:47:57.706: g_object_get: assertion 'G_IS_OBJECT (object)' failed
Xlib:  extension "DPMS" missing on display ":0.0".

(xfce4-power-manager:10572): xfce4-power-manager-WARNING **: 16:47:57.706: Cannot get DPMSInfo
Xlib:  extension "DPMS" missing on display ":0.0".

(xfce4-power-manager:10572): GLib-GObject-CRITICAL **: 16:47:57.706: g_object_get: assertion 'G_IS_OBJECT (object)' failed

(xfce4-power-manager:10572): GLib-GObject-CRITICAL **: 16:47:57.706: g_object_get: assertion 'G_IS_OBJECT (object)' failed
free(): invalid pointer
Aborted

But when I launch it when the charger is plugged in then it works. I can see it;s icon in the panel as well. So, how can I make it run when laptop is running on battery?
Thanks.

Watch sudo journalctl  --follow as you plug and unplug your charger. The ...DPMS... error message hints that you' re running a GUI tool on a non-GUI  terminal, or bugly suspended display

@waltinator nothing happens...i mean i don't see any error in the log.
